# ERROR TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: error-handling

Request help in following code

```
model = LinearRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 3)
X_rfe = rfe.fit_transform(X,y)
model.fit(X_rfe,y)
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.support_)
```

Comment: Let me know the solution if you found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 2):

Put: n_features_to_select = 3

That worked for me.